# VirtualHost using httpd on Fedora is not showing the relative index.html content

Tags: apache, virtualhost, fedora

My system (virtual machine):

NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="39 (Thirty Nine)"

My httpd version:

```
httpd -v
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.58 (Fedora Linux)
Server built:   Oct 20 2023 00:00:00

My VirtualHost file named as 00-test is located in /etc/httpd/conf.d:

```
<Directory /site1> 
Require all granted 
AllowOverride None 
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:8070>
DocumentRoot "/site1"
</VirtualHost>
```

My index.html file is located in /site1 and both the file and directory have complete permission level
chmod a+rwx).

Additional info:

- i have disabled and stopped firewalld with

```
systemctl disable firewalld
```

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

- i have reloaded and restarted httpd service with

```
systemctl reload httpd
```

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

- i rebooted the system.
- About httpd.conf located in /etc/httpd/conf:
  Listens to port 80. I created an Index.html in the directory specified (/var/www/html) and it works.

I am trying to create a VirtualHost and i am expecting to see the index.html content when I do

```
curl localhost:8070
```

but I doesn't happen.

I am restarting (I tried also reloading) httpd each time I do a change.

Chatgpt keeps iterating to me the same responses.

On /var/log/httpd/error_log I don't see related errors and checking httpd with systemctl status httpd I can see that the service is active (also like said the "main" configuration with httpd.conf is working). Hoping I gave all the useful information.

Comment: I thought that maybe there is some line of "code" in the httpd.conf file that might be the reason of my problem. Any idea about that? I saw this line "IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf" and if comment it nothing happens. But I think that it should not be commented if I want the conf.d files to be used (so I removed the comment). I'm honestly starting to think that maybe there is something magical that runs my system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. The configuration file of the Virtual Host in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d`
directory must end with `.conf` extension.

So I did

```
mv 00-test 00-test.conf
```

and now it's working... I hope this can help someone else.